# connecting user specific DBus session in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, dbus

in Python-dbus one can connect user specific dbus like ..

```
import dbus
bus1 = dbus.bus.BusConnection("tcp:host=192.168.1.1,port=1234")
```

how can one achive the same in QtDbus in C++ ? all I can find is Just are static functions, like 
    QDBusConnection::SessionBus or QDBusConnection::SystemBus ... and possibility to connect the other user specific bus seems to be missing in QtDbus/C++ ?

any example code or hint are welcomed.

Comment: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/Accessing_Interfaces

Comment: hi Karl, I want to listen to signals from a remote session bus, which I am broadcasting over TCP/IP..

using above python call, I can connect to remote dbus... but how to do this in Qt ?  QDBusConnection::SessionBus or QDBusConnection::SystemBus are very session and machine dependent..., and the techbase.kde article you pointed using session and system bus :( ..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using `QDBusConnection::connectToBus(QString&,QString&)`. Something like:

```
bus = QDBusConnection::connectToBus("tcp:host=192.168.1.1,port=1234", "mybus");
```